# running bash code from php button

Tags: javascript, php, linux

I want to test 4 files in Linux server through PHP, and the display result should show in the text area. let me know whats the correct way to solve this.

Sh test_batch.sh

```
$ {dict_file} $ {locale} $ {keyboard_layout} $ {golden_test_file} $ 
{auto_correction_file} (optional)
```

[image: those are the four files with check box]

```
 if (isset($_POST['files'])) {
 foreach ($_POST['files'] as $value) {
 echo $dir . $value . '<br />';
 $result = shell_exec('sudo sh test_batch.sh $dir .$value. ');

  }
  }else {
  exit('No files selected');
  }
  }
   ?>
                            <br/>
                            <table>
                             <tr>
                    <td><b>Result to Display and Save:</b></td></tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                    <textarea disabled id="inputTextToSave"  style="width:512px;height:256px" value = "'.$result.'"></textarea>`
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should refrain from ever using sudo in a web script to do anything.  What if someone decided to feed your server the string *"&& rm -rf /"* in your $_POST and that got concatenated into your *sudo sh test_batch.sh $dir .$value* string?  That would make for a very bad day.

Instead, consider implementing whatever test_batch.sh does into some kind of worker script that processes requests queued to it (you could do this in Perl, PHP, with Node.JS...there are a few ways.